# Using Index versus Create Index in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, ddl

I am creating a table with following script (I used Using index).

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
    C1 VARCHAR2(2 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    C2 VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (C1) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SFE_I1
)
TABLESPACE SFE_D1;
```

In the above query index will create for what column?

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_TABLE ON TABLE1 (C1) TABLESPACE SFE_I1;
```

If I am creating index with the above create index query, it will create index for C1 column. But what is the difference between to this two scripts.

As well if I run both this query, what should happen. And what is the suggested way to do this?

If my create table script contains composite primary key and i am using USING INDEX keyword then how index will be created (will it create a single index for all the composite columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of the `create table` statement, for this question, is the `CONSTRAINT TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (C1) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SFE_I1`. Let's break it down and understand it:

```
CONSTRAINT TABLE_PK
```

You're creating a constraint named `table_pk`.

```
PRIMARY KEY
```

This constraint is a primary key

```
(C1)
```

On the column `c1`

```
USING INDEX TABLESPACE SFE_I1
```

A primary key, implicitly needs to create an index so it can efficiently search for duplicates that would violate the constraint. Like with explicitly created indexes (e.g., your second statement), the index would be created on the user's default tablespace, which isn't always the best idea. The `using index tablespace` syntax allows you do define which tablespace to use, in the same way you can use it when creating an index.

If you attempt to run **both** statements the second one should fail, since `c1` is already indexed by the first one.

Comment: If USING INDEX is not used in the First query of the above post, will it create index by default? If Yes, how can we see the index?
If composite primary create with using index, then will it create index considering all the involved composite columns.

Comment: If i want to create a index for a column which is not primary key, then what are all the condition should be satisfied (For example, if the column is capable of producing duplicate values)

Comment: @Yoga a primary key will always create an index, which is has the same name as the primary key. If you omit the `using index tablespace` clause, it will be created on the default tablespace. If you have a composite key, it will create a composite index.  You can create an index on a column with duplicate values. If you attempt to create a `unique index`, though, it will fail.